# How to create dynamic html

Tags: html

My question is really wiered.
I am working on a advertisement website. I was checking some other websites as following

http://www.XXXXXXX.com/XXXXX/XXXXXX/YYYY-available-3+1-YYYY-YYYYY-road.html

My Question is when I browse any ad in website,its opening a html file with title of Ad.
if website has 10000 ads, I am sure they will not create 10000 html file. but while browsing the ads, we can see the URL like above.

YYYY-available-3+1-YYYY-YYYYY-road.html
basically it was a title of Ad. now how I can do this.

I have implemented in jsp with dynamic values. but I want to implement as above.
please help and suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map `*.html` to a servlet in the web.xml file. In this servlet, parse the URL of the request and transform it to some advertisement ID or name. Get the text of the Ad in your database of ads using the ID or name you parsed, and send the text of the ad to the response.